# SetRetainInstance in Xamarin not showing

Tags: xamarin.android

i've searched google for this but i really can't. i'm so desparete i've even searched second page.

intelliense does not know any `setRetainInstance`
my fragment is not in backstack, and when I change the screen orientation, the app crashes, please tell me how to implement the `setRetainIncetance` in xamarin

i know that it calls the fragments default constructor when it tries to re create the fragment but i do not want that because it creates unwanted behavior.

```
public class FragHome : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        Context context;

        public FragHome(Context c)
        {
            context = c;
        }


        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here


        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Home, container, false);

            //test codes


            return view;



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I haven't used this myself but after some searching, I found out that unlike Android, it is a property in Xamarin. So assuming you want to do something like `setRetainInstance (true)` in Android, then in Xamarin you will need to do:

```
yourFrag.RetainInstance = true;
```

If you want to do the same inside your `FragHome` class, then the following should suffice:

```
this.RetainInstance = true;
```

For more info, you can start [from here.](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.Fragment.RetainInstance/)